# Excel - Aggregations

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, aggregate-functions

REPOSTING WITH EDITS:
I am trying to get a column with the `MINIMUM` and the `MAXIMUM` monetary order values (G.T. Base) per person, split into the first order and the last order of the person itself.

Each person (Bill to name) has different orders and different value of orders (GT base). I calculated which is the FIRST order for that person and the LAST order for that person but I am not able to associate the monetary value (GT base) to that first order for that person and for that last order for that person.
Please see example attached.

[image]

Comment: So you want to look at the name and the First order date to return the value in the first order value?

Comment: Use the SUMIFS() approach described in the duplicate.

Comment: in `D2` insert `=INDEX($G$2:$G$11,MATCH(B2&$F2,$A$2:$A$11&$F$2:$F$11,0))` if you don't like the `SUMIFS()` approach.

Comment: Thanks Zipa but this gives me a VALUE error...